# How do I remove this white space while using CSS grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am just learning how to use CSS grid layout from a crash course. While tinkering around with the grid-template-columns property, a white space has appeared under one of my cat images that I cannot get rid of.

[image: The space]

This is my HTML:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 1fr;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <main>
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" alt='' />
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" alt='' />
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt='' />
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people" alt='' />
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" alt='' />
    </div>
</main>
```

Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Your first three images are on the first row and the rest are on the second row. If you make all your images the same size it should fix it. You can do this in css but it’s best to have all the original images be the right size or close to it.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the current size and just move the images up where the white space is?

Comment: Also your ‘img {}’ block cant go inside another block in CSS, unless you are using a preprocessor like SCSS or LESS. You probably want a new block with ‘.gallery img {}’ instead.

Comment: Yeah I am actually using SASS. Should have mentioned that

Comment: I'm not a grid expert but I just read through the CSS Tricks page on it, and I think @Temani Afif is correct. Grid seems to support only exact grids, where the cells all line up. You can get around that by making images span multiple cells. If you need something more like a "brick wall layout", maybe a vertical flexbox layout would work better.

Answer (score 1):

Make the third image into 3 rows:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 1fr;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" >
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" >
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" >
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people" >
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" >
</div>
```

Comment: It does not scale properly

Comment: @ZohirSalak how it's supposed to scale?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you want to have happen instead.

`grid-template-columns` specifies your grid columns. By setting it to: `200px 200px 1fr` you're basically instructing the browser:

- There should be 3 columns for my content.
- Set the first and second columns to 200px wide
- Use flex for the third column.

So instead, one option would be to make use of a [repeat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat). The following will make 3 equal columns:

```
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also, FWIW keep an eye on both your HTML and CSS. In the HTML, you should have closing tag for `<main></main>`. And if you're working with vanilla CSS (not Sass or Less), your declarations for `img` should be outside those for `.gallery`.